# indexing for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I want to do the following:

I create a matrix with all possible permutations from `1:n`, for example

```
n=4;
L=perms(1:n)';
```

I get as output as expected a *4*-by-*24* matrix:

```
L =

  Columns 1 through 13

     4     4     4     4     4     4     3     3     3     3     3     3     
     3     3     2     2     1     1     4     4     2     2     1     1     
     2     1     3     1     2     3     2     1     4     1     2     4     
     1     2     1     3     3     2     1     2     1     4     4     2     

  Columns 14 through 24

     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1
     3     4     4     1     1     3     3     2     2     4     4
     1     3     1     4     3     2     4     3     4     2     3
     4     1     3     3     4     4     2     4     3     3     2
```

Now I want to use this matrix for the indexes of a `for` loop:

Using the first column, I want to feed the input of my loop the following indexes: `i=4` `j=3`,`2`,`1`. Then for `i=3` `j=2`,`1`. Then for `i=2` `j=1`. `i=1` is empty

This could be done just for the first column like this:

```
for u=4:-1:1
    for v=u-1:-1:1
```

But will not work for other columns so I need to do the same but with the entries of matrix `L`, something like (it doesn't work in MATLB) for column `i=1`:

```
u=L(1:4,1)
v=L(u:L(4,1) , 1) %// where u corresponds to L(1,1) then L(2,1) then L(3,1)
```

(for all the columns it would look like:

```
for i=1:length(L)
    for u=L(4*(i-1)+1:4*i)
        for v=.. ?
```

)

This doesn't work because MATLAB takes the values of the entries and when I write `L(1,1):L(4,1)` it doesn't mean return the entries from line one to line four but rather all the numbers with increment `1` from the value of `L(1,1)` to the value of `L(4,1)` (here empty).

Any ideas ? thank you very much in advance

Comment: For loops over arrays need row vectors, try looping over `L(1:4,1).'` (mind the transpose).

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this will solve you problem.

```
for col = 1:size(L,2)
    rowIdx = 1;
    for j = [L(:,col)]'
        for k = [L(rowIdx:end,col)]'
        % Do your stuff here 

        end
        rowIdx = rowIdx + 1;
    end
end
```

Notice how I use the values from columns from L directly as loop index variable.  In a `for` loop statement you can basically write any row vector and the index takes those values. For example

```
for i = [1, 7, 11, 14, 23]
    disp(i); % prints 1,7,11,14,23
end
```

This is true for arrays of objects, cell arrays, basically any single row matrix.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly!!  I get exactly what i want with a mini modification "for k = [L(rowIdx+:end,col)]'"  instead of for k = [L(rowIdx:end,col)]' (when n=4, for each iteration I get 6 matrices x 24 which is a little bit better than 10 matrices x 24). Very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for col = 1:size(L, 2)
    for I = 1:n-1
        for J = I:n
            i = L(I,col);
            j = L(J,col);
            %// As an example just print out the loop variable values
            disp(sprintf('Col:%d\ti:%d\tj:%d\r\n',col,i,j))
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @AndrasDeak nope, should have tested it first. Works now... (btw there were many problems aside from the column vector issues)